# Does the .NET GC reserve a fixed heap size on the initialization or does it just grow on demand?

Tags: .net, garbage-collection, clr

I was reading the following article about the [fundamentals .Net GC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/fundamentals#generations) and I have some follow-up questions

The article mentions the following

> 1. By default, on 32-bit computers, each process has a 2-GB user-mode
>    virtual address space.
> 2. As an application developer, you work only with virtual address
>    space and never manipulate physical memory directly. The garbage
>    collector allocates and frees virtual memory for you on the managed
>    heap.

My follow-up question is: does the GC allocates all the 2GB at once for the heap or it keeps growing it or remove from it as needed? The same article says After the garbage collector is initialized by the CLR, it allocates a segment of memory to store and manage objects so does that mean that it starts with initial size and keep growing to the max allowed size or as the available memory allows?

In the memory allocation section the article mentions that

> the runtime reserves a contiguous region of address space for the
> process

That is a clear statement but but when it talks about the generations and specifically about the generation 3 it says

> Generation 3 is a physical generation that's logically collected as
> part of generation 2.

what does physical generation logically connected as part of Gen2 mean? does that mean that might not mean within the same contiguous block and somehow known as part of this heap?

Appreciate your help in advance.

Comment: It starts small and keeps growing. It's contiguous when it starts, it may become fragmented as it gets larger. Generation 3 is a strange term, it's normally just called the LOH, it's a separate heap, collected at the same time as Gen2. Try to stick to one question only

Comment: Agreed with @Charlieface. Term Gen 3 it's quite confusing.Your article mention that also: "However, if they are large objects, they go on the large object heap (LOH), which is sometimes referred to as generation 3."

Comment: Thanks @Charlieface and Qwerty Qwerty, Just to confirm the fragmentation understanding here, can we say that every memory segment reserved at a time should be contiguous and that the heap might be defragmented and that it is a composition of those different segments that has been reserved overall the life of the running process? 

Just to reply to the one question tip, I just saw that both questions are related and better to discuss them as one topic.

Comment: Give or take, yeah that's about right. Although there can also be internal fragmentation after objects are deleted during GC. No, these appear to be different questions

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and appreciate the tip.